# How to use Lucene for next token recommendation?

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to build a recommender that suggests the next token based on some context. An example would be recommending method calls where the context would be the method calls that were seen before.

I would need Lucene to build a language model (e.g. the n-gram model) from a prebuilt list of strings. It should then support queries that contain a list of tokens (the context) and return the token that has the highest probability to come next.

What would be the best way to implement this with the Lucene API?

edit:
I tried the suggestion from femtoRgon to try the Suggesters from the suggest package. Unfortunately, they don't completely solve my use case. AnalyzingSuggester and AnalyzingInfixSuggester need to be built with query data,
while I want to build the model with a list of strings or text.

The FreeTextSuggester is pretty close to what I need but it does not support context. While it builds an n-gram model from the text and the autocompletion works, I would also like to input a context. The context would be a list of strings, for example when using it with method calls it would be the tokens seen before the triggering the code completion.

Would there be a way to use such context in these suggesters or is there another method in Lucene?

Comment: Take a look at the [`org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.analyzing`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/suggest/analyzing/) package, particularly the Suggester classes (Mike McCandless has written posts about a couple of them, [here](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/09/lucenes-new-analyzing-suggester.html) and [here](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2013/06/a-new-lucene-suggester-based-on-infix.html))

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142221